# Exclude folders from being scanned by shotwell

Tags: 10.10, gnome, configuration, multimedia, shotwell

I have a phone (an HTC Hero) and when I plug it into my computer, Shotwell shows me my photos and some other files that are on some applications folders that I don't want to import.

Everytime I unselect these photos, but a better solution would be to exclude these folders from being scanned by shotwell.

Any suggestions on how to do this please?

Comment: Does making the folder Hidden stop it from being scanned eg adding a period to the beginning of the folder name

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an issue with gphoto2, the library Shotwell relies on to work with digital cameras.  I've reported this [bug here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3000202&group_id=8874&atid=108874).

Our own ticket for this problem is here: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/1903

There's a number of ways to solve this problem.  One question I have for you is, are all the photos you want to import stored in a single directory on your phone or multiple directories?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will wait :(. All photos are on multiple directories.